# Does the Window object have methods to get/set keys on it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I'm aware that I can simply write `window.myValue = 'something'`, but I was wondering if there was some official mechanism to set/get keys on the `Window`.

Something I can map to an interface, like:

```
window.setValue('myKey', 'myValue')
window.getValue('myKey')
```

Explanation:

I'm trying to practice dependency inversion and would like to take a interface which maps to the Window.

```
interface GetterSetter {
  setValue(key: string, value: any): void
  getValue(key: string): any
}

function addHi(target: GetterSetter) {
  target.setValue('Hi', 'Marco')
}

addHi(window)
```

Comment: `window.myValue = 'something'` works perfectly fine, what sort of more official version were you hoping for?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a functional way to set and retrieve keys, you can use Reflect:

```js
Reflect.set(window, 'myKey', 'myValue');
console.log(Reflect.get(window, 'myKey'));
```

This works with any object, not just `window`.

(but there's absolutely nothing wrong with using ordinary dot notation)